# Comparing probability of drawing two red cards one by one without replacement with drawing two red cards at the same time

Tags: probability

I've a question related to probability, I think the probability of withdrawing two red card together from a deck of playing cards will never be the same as of drawing two red card one by one without replacing them to the deck of cards. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are wrong.  Could you show us the probabilities that you obtained in each case and how you obtained them so that we can see where the source of your confusion originates?

Comment: Compare $\dfrac{26 \choose 2}{52 \choose 2}$ with $\dfrac{26}{52}\times \dfrac{25}{51}$

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a plausible scenario that would suggest the two probabilities in question are "never" equal? If yes explain it to us, and we shall try to find the flaw.

The story is about an experiment. Two cards are selected from a deck and  you inspect the result. Assume that you don't perform the experiment yourself, but have an honest slave making the selection. Do you really think it makes a difference whether (i) the slave shuffles the deck thoroughly, then takes the top two cards between two fingers, (ii) the slave shuffles the deck thoroughly, then picks two cards one after the other at random from the deck without looking at them, or (iii) the slave shuffles the deck thoroughly, then picks a random card, looks at it and then picks another random card from the deck?

Comment: No other scenario came to my mind, but some confusion was there. Now I think I've to revise  probability chapter...